# Access cell's index when button pressed?

Tags: swift

I'm adding cells to my table view which have 2 labels and a button. When the button inside each cell is pressed I need to access that cell's index inside the target function. Here's what I have so far:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "person", for: indexPath) as! personTableCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = searchResults[indexPath.row].name
        cell.emailLabel.text = searchResults[indexPath.row].email
        cell.inviteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(NewGroupVC.addInvite), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }

    func addInvite(sender:UIButton!) {
        print("Invite pressed")
    }
```

How would I get the index of the button's cell inside the `addInvite` function?

Comment: Since you seem to use only one section with multiple row, you can add a tag to your button, and read it in `addInvite()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your buttons are in the same section, set the `tag` property of your `inviteButton` to the row index:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "person", for: indexPath) as! personTableCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = searchResults[indexPath.row].name
    cell.emailLabel.text = searchResults[indexPath.row].email
    cell.inviteButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.inviteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(NewGroupVC.addInvite), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    return cell
}

func addInvite(sender:UIButton!) {
    print("Invite pressed for row \(sender.tag)")
}
```

If your buttons are spread over multiple sections and you want to know which button from which section was pressed, subclass `UIButton` to add an `indexPath` property:

```
class MyButton : UIButton {
    var indexPath: IndexPath?
}

class personTableCell {
    var inviteButton: MyButton
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    cell.inviteButton.indexPath = indexPath
    // ...
}

func addInvite(sender:MyButton!) {
    print("Invite pressed for index \(sender.indexPath)")
}
```

Comment: This is bad advice. Never use `tag` to store the index path. And never add an `indexPath` property to a cell. The tag or indexPath will be wrong if the table view allows rows to be deleted, inserted, or moved.